# Changing property values in WPF Data Context from another class/ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to understand data context and how properties within different viewmodels are applied to a window in WPF.

Let's say I have a simple sample form with the following codebehind:

## XAML Code Behind

```
    public partial class pageTest : Page
    {
        public pageTest ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new AnotherClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's assume we have a property in the `AnotherClass` class that is a boolean called `Visible`. This visible value is used to collapse and show a particular element.

Now, my confusion lies in understanding how to manipulate this `Visible` property from another ViewModel. Seeing that I create a particular instance of the `AnotherClass` class, what would be the proper method of changing the `Visible` property from another ViewModel at another point in time?

Comment: _"what would be the proper method of changing the Visible property from another ViewModel at another point in time?"_ -- there's not enough context in your question to keep it from being too broad. The short answer is simply that you change the property when you need to, making sure you design your model data structures so that they have access to the object(s) they need when they need them. In such scenarios, your `AnotherClass` object isn't created nor exists in isolation. The data structures would be set up so that whatever other object needs to manipulate it, has a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... usually you'll try to avoid code behind in WPF and go the MVVM way.

Regardless of that, you'll have to either make that property static, so it lives across instances, or inject the instance using Dependency Injection (DI), so whomever needs to change it has access to that object.

For a (biased) mvvm review, you can check out [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template).

I highly suggest going that way and probably looking DI as well, since they are plenty of frameworks do help you with that (ninject and autofac pop to mind, but google it up, there's plenty).

Comment: I don't know much about MVVM, but what am I violating here? I plan on doing everything in the ViewModel and not in the codebehind. The only thing in the codebehind is the DataContext assignment. Is this something that should be avoided?

Comment: Initially, I had a bunch of static classes, but wasn't sure if that's actually the best way to go about it or not. I'm confused seeing people say this.DataContext = new ViewModelClass(); How does anything else access that instantiation of that class?

Comment: you can do whatever you want TBH. The class doesn't have to be static. you can make the property static. you can have a manager that will return the class for you, so on first call it'll create (and save it as local var), and on subsequent, will return the same one.

Comment: "How does anything else access that instantiation of that class?" Like any other class would access any other class in any application. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 inject it and control the object ... ? not sure what you're asking tbh

Comment: @mm8 :) ... oh ...then you should have commented on his question i guess. makes sense.